# How to find the distance between two CG points?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When we do multitouch with two fingers in a UIScrollView, we get two CG points. I want to find the distance between them. Then when again we do the pinch(inside or outside), Then we will again get two points. Then after finding the distance again between these two points , I want to decide whether I pinched in or out. If i have pinched in, surely the new distance will be lesser and vice versa.

But don't know how to find an accurate measurement for the distance between 2 points for doing comparison ? Is anyone having idea about this ?

Comment: See [my answer for Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036132/1966109) that shows up to 5 different ways to find the distance between two `CGPoint`s.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Distance between `p1` and `p2`:

```
CGFloat xDist = (p2.x - p1.x);
CGFloat yDist = (p2.y - p1.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist);
```

Put in a function:

```
func distance(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let xDist = a.x - b.x
    let yDist = a.y - b.y
    return CGFloat(sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist))
}
```

Background: [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

If you only need to calculate if the distance between the points increases or decreases, you can omit the sqrt() which will make it a little faster.

Comment: Is there no convenience method for this?

Comment: Computational geometry axiom #1: if you are *comparing* distances, there is no need to incur the cost of the sqrt() operation.

Comment: @SpaceyRicochet there are methods hypotf and ccpDistance. See answers below.

Comment: @QED Does the value before you take the square root have a name or significance beyond an intermediate step of calculating the distance?

Comment: @AllenHumphreys nothing I know of more poetic than *distance squared*.

Answer (score 195):

You can use the `hypot()` or `hypotf()` function to calculate the hypotenuse. Given two points `p1` and `p2`:

```
CGFloat distance = hypotf(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);
```

And that's it.

Comment: if using swift it's distance = hypotf(Float(p1.x) - Float(p2.x), Float(p1.y) - Float(p2.y))

Comment: you mean `let distance = hypotf(Float(p1.x - p2.x), Float(p1.y - p2.y))`

Comment: you mean `let distance = hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y)` since Swift 2.1

Comment: This function is actually the reason why I searched this question.

Answer (score 32):

**For swift users**

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow(x - point.x, 2) + pow(y - point.y, 2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

With Swift 4, you may choose one of the 5 following Playground codes in order to get the distance between two `CGPoint` instances.

---

### 1. Using Darwin `sqrt(_:)` function

```
import CoreGraphics

func distance(from lhs: CGPoint, to rhs: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let xDistance = lhs.x - rhs.x
    let yDistance = lhs.y - rhs.y
    return sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance)
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: -10, y: -100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 600)

distance(from: point1, to: point2) // 701.141925718324
```

---

### 2. Using `CGFloat` `squareRoot()` method

```
import CoreGraphics

func distance(from lhs: CGPoint, to rhs: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let xDistance = lhs.x - rhs.x
    let yDistance = lhs.y - rhs.y
    return (xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance).squareRoot()
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: -10, y: -100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 600)

distance(from: point1, to: point2) // 701.141925718324
```

---

### 3. Using `CGFloat` `squareRoot()` method and Core Graphics `pow(_:_:)` function

```
import CoreGraphics

func distance(from lhs: CGPoint, to rhs: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return (pow(lhs.x - rhs.x, 2) + pow(lhs.y - rhs.y, 2)).squareRoot()
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: -10, y: -100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 600)

distance(from: point1, to: point2) // 701.141925718324
```

---

### 4. Using Core Graphics `hypot(_:_:)` function

```
import CoreGraphics

func distance(from lhs: CGPoint, to rhs: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return hypot(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: -10, y: -100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 600)

distance(from: point1, to: point2) // 701.141925718324
```

---

### 5. Using Core Graphics `hypot(_:_:)` function and `CGFloat` `distance(to:)` method

```
import CoreGraphics

func distance(from lhs: CGPoint, to rhs: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    return hypot(lhs.x.distance(to: rhs.x), lhs.y.distance(to: rhs.y))
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: -10, y: -100)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 600)

distance(from: point1, to: point2) // 701.141925718324
```

Comment: Works in Swift 3 too.

Answer (score 12):

```
-(float)distanceFrom:(CGPoint)point1 to:(CGPoint)point2
{
CGFloat xDist = (point2.x - point1.x);
CGFloat yDist = (point2.y - point1.y);
return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}
```

***If you are using cocos2d***

```
float distance = ccpDistance(point1, point2);
```

Comment: It appears ccpDistance is part of cocos2d, not part of core. Including it to avoid the pythagorean theorem is probably overkill.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this, I use it a lot:

```
- (float) distanceBetween : (CGPoint) p1 and: (CGPoint) p2
{
    return sqrt(pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+pow(p2.y-p1.y,2));
}
```

Call like this:

```
float distanceMoved = [self distanceBetween touchStart and: touchEnd];
```

I normally use cocos2d, but I still use my own function for some things because when I was learning I wrote a bunch of my own functions for simple stuff rather than searching for the "official" higher order functions, and additionally I'm not a big fan of functions(vars, vars), I prefer [self functions vars and: vars]

Comment: shouldn't it be sqrt(pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+pow(p2.y-p1.y,2))? second occurrence of p2.y replaced p1.y.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the absolute distance value between two points then you can use (for Cocos2d):

```
float distance = abs(ccpDistance(point1, point2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define rw_pointOffset(point1, point2) CGPointMake(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y)
#define rw_pointDistance(point1, point2) sqrtf( powf(point2.x - point1.x, 2.0f) + powf(point2.y - point1.y, 2.0f))
```

And that´s how you use it:

```
CGPoint offset = rw_pointOffset(view1.center, view2.center);
float distance = rw_pointDistance(view1.center, view2.center);
```