# Move actions while animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm attempting to have a character move across the screen from point A to point B on user touch.

I'm currently doing this with SKActions (in a group). However, I've noticed that SKActions take a duration, so there will be not constant movement speed which is a deal breaker. Closer distances will cause the character to move slower while far way distances make the character move faster.

Is there a better way for doing this? I was thinking in using the -update method in the scene but not sure what would be the best way to tie this into the touch events.

Any recommendations?

Comment: why can't you do dynamic duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do this with SKAction and grouping...

First you'll want to calculate the distance between the two points, `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` (Pythagorean Theorem) kind of thing. Then figure out from a constant speed how quickly or how slow the character should move based off c^2.

Then just send that variable to the `SKAction` function you make up. That way it's dynamic.

```
-(SKAction*)startActionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval {
    SKAction* action = [SKAction moveToX:1.0 duration:timeInterval];
    return action;
}
```

Comment: I feel this is easier (cleaner?) to do in Cocos2D by having a constant speed in the -update method for the CCNode. I guess I was kind of hoping to get some direction on how to do that with SpriteKit.

Comment: I see, you don't want to do the math, you want the SDK to auto do it for you. Well, unfortunate from my experience there isn't a mathless way to do it because of what you pointed out, everything is based on duration.

Comment: Just wrap it in a function, that calculates the duration for you, given a speed and point... (speed = d/t), some simple algebra and you can calculate it.

Comment: This is a really easy task to complete mate. You are really limited yourself if you expect your SDKs to do everything for you. I could write this function in less then 2 minutes and you'd be ready to go, but that's not the point of developing. You need to learn things too..

Comment: @JohnRiselvato yes it is, where did I suggest otherwise? My question was directed towards the API more than anything.

Comment: Well I guess because you said you would rather go to Cocos2d, I was under the impression of that. I hope someone with more SK knowledge comes in here and can answer you question properly then.

Comment: @MrShoot I think this answer was correct. A look at the API reference will confirm that it doesn't have an equivalent. John was giving you exactly what you needed to get the equivalent. He could have just said "no", if the question was in regards to having an API equivalent. So, he went an extra step for you in my opinion, an he did utilize the API in combination with math.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is calculate the duration yourself using the distance and speed.

speed = distance/time, time being your duration, so solve for t.

Using some pseduo code here:

```
function moveToWithSpeed(p1, endPoint: p2, speed: speed)
{
//credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906511/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-cg-points
CGFloat xDist = (p2.x - p1.x);
CGFloat yDist = (p2.y - p1.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
duration = distance/speed

SKAction.moveTo(p2, duration: duration);
}
```

The rest I think you can figure out yourself.

Comment: this + mine = everything you need.

Comment: Another step would be to have the method return a SKAction as in the other answer, so that you can still group/sequence them as needed. Voted for this answer, just a suggestion to the poster to take note of that aspect of the other answer, as that will potentially be your next issue.

Comment: That's how I did it :)

Comment: What's the measure of speed in this case? p/s?

Comment: if my answer is incorrect, I clearly don't understand your question then. As I understood it, you wanted a way to have constant movement speed.