# Subview constraints for dragging

Tags: objective-c

The color palette is a view added to main storyboard. I have used corner radius to make a circle. The small circle inside the palette is a subview created inside the palette view. The small circle is draggable. The problem is I can drag the small circle outside the main circle (palette).

How do I stop the small circle from being dragged once it reaches the border of the main circle (palette).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the distance between the centre point of the palette and the centre point of the picker circle ([How to find the distance between two CG points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906511/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-cg-points))

Add on the radius of the picker circle and if that exceeds the radius of the larger circle then you want to stop the dragging.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

So if the Distance + R2 is >= Radius 1 you've reached the edge of the circle and need to stop them dragging

**UPDATE2**

Based on the sample project you uploaded here is the correct code...

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches){


        CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        newPoint.x -= startPoint.x;
        newPoint.y -= startPoint.y;
        CGRect frm = [picker frame];
        frm.origin = newPoint;

        CGFloat xDist = abs((newPoint.x + 15) - (self.center.x - self.frame.origin.x));
        CGFloat yDist = abs((newPoint.y + 15) - (self.center.y - self.frame.origin.y));

        CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

        if ((distance + 15) >= (self.frame.size.width /2)) {
            // EDGE REACHED SO DON'T UPDATE
        } else {
            [picker setFrame:frm];
        }

    }
}
```

You only want to update the frame if its still in bounds and your distance calculations weren't taking into account the offset of the containing view

HTH

Comment: I don't understand the second part

Comment: @DivinePropotion I've added a bit more with your drawn updated

Comment: I am still having a hard time achieving this. Could you please review my code and let me know what I am doing wrong. This code is placed inside paletteView class. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7494466/

Comment: @DivinePropotion had a quick look, couple of things, use the `center` properties of the views rather than calculate it. you've stated that your picker is 30 x 30 then the radius should be 15 not 18.75? Palette radius should be 137.5. Also put some `NSLog` in to see that your points match up, e.g. if the picker is in the center of the palette are their center points the same? Is pickerVIew a sub view of the palette? You might need to adjust the picker center by the origin of the palette?

Comment: What do you mean by adjust the picker center by the origin of the palette?

Comment: Still no luck. I tried writing the program from scratch. Distance is much larger than the radius of circleView. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7535045/

Comment: You need to show me how you are adding the the 2 views, is the small circle a subview of the palette, or are they both added to a superview

Comment: and yes. small circle is a subview of big circle (palette/wheel)

Comment: I have uploaded a sample app with my code. Can you please have a look for me. Thank you for all the help you have provided so far. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tys09q909kwrq7i/AACrZ8Ss3OJJpXWutI5Gtgjoa/ios-app