# SpriteKit - Bouncing node constant speed/velocity?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

[image]

Simple setup - I have bouncing ball nodes (blue) and static ball nodes (green). The grey box has Physics body `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: box.frame)`, so it limits the bouncing ball from moving outside. I set the bouncing balls node (blue) velocity to a random `CGVector` upon creation and it starts moving. It bounces off the static ball node (green), and off the edges of the grey box.

My general `SKPhysicsBody` setup with all nodes is:

```
node.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
node.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
node.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
node.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
```

My question is: How do I make sure the bouncing ball does move at a *constant* speed? After a couple of bounces, the node is either speeding up, or slowing down.

Comment: You can set physicsBody.velocity Any time.

Comment: But how to keep it constant?

Comment: Set the value to a constant number, you may use contact delegate and set the value as same as they began contacting.

Comment: I notice its a CGVector. You need to normalize the value with hypot() to get the vector length and keep this length same all the time. It's a simple calculation and you can find anywhere.

Comment: That was actually the right clue, thanks a lot. Do you want to write a response so I can accept it, or should I answer this question myself?

Comment: You can answer it yourself if you have the helpful code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this, I normalized the vector whenever the physics engine detects a collision. So in `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`, the following happens:

```
let length = hypotf(Float(node.velocity.dx), Float(node.velocity.dy)) 
let multiplier = (290.0 / length)
firstBody.velocity.dx *= CGFloat(multiplier)
firstBody.velocity.dy *= CGFloat(multiplier)
```

`290.0` is an arbitrary value that determines the speed of ball.

For reference, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808621/spritekit-how-to-turn-touches-into-vectors-of-uniform-speed).