# How to calculate distance from center point to a particular point on UIView

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have a UIView in a circular view form and I want to set center point is min.value and UIView height is max value i.e 40ft. Can any one help me to calculate distance between min and max value at run time?

Comment: `let distance = max - min` // or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Suppose I have drag ball in between max and min value how i will  know that ball is drop at 20 ft

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the distance between two CG points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906511/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-cg-points)

Comment: @PGDev I want to divide my UIView into 0 to 40 ft max and calculate point, But in Actual my UIView is 300 *300

Comment: Any one have solution ?

Comment: To me it's not quite clear what you are looking for. It might be helpful if you post some code to show what you did and what you are asking for.