# How to get the distance between two anchors?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, layout-anchor

I know [how to get the distance between two points in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984383/8377123). But I want to know how to get the distance between two anchors as a CGFloat.

For example: I want to find the distance between the

```
view.topAnchor
```

and the

```
button.topAnchor
```

on a view controller like this:
[image]

I'm guessing I will have to get a CGPoint of the anchors (then I can just find the difference between the y points of the CGPoint's). I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Anchors are actually there to construct constraints. If you are already using them you can get the value just by using constraint.constant property. Like This,

```
let view = UIView()
let button = UIButton()
view.addSubview(button)

let heightConstraint = button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
view.layoutIfNeeded() // update incase still not updated
print(heightConstraint.constant)
```

But I think what you actually trying to achieve is,

```
let distance = button.frame.minY - view.frame.minY
```

measuring the distance like this.