# Issue with scaling when UIView is rotated upside down

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to rotate and scale `UIView` which has `UIImageView` inside as `subView` with one finger using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. both rotation and scaling works fine in regular situations but when view is rotated upside down then it works in opposite direction instead of scaling up it scales down and vice versa, also when rotated at corner points it kind of flickers, don't work properly. results are shown in these gifs :

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ASzb.gif)

[another issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQx1A.gif)

here is how i'm trying to achieve this :

```
   @objc func ScaleGest(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let gestureSuperView = gesture.view?.superview else { return }

    let center = frameScaleBut.center
    let touchLocation = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    
    if gesture.state == UIPanGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        self.initialDistance = distance(center, touchLocation)
    } else if gesture.state == UIPanGestureRecognizer.State.changed {
        
        let dist = distance(center, touchLocation) - initialDistance
        
        let smallScale: CGFloat = editingMode == .sticker ? 90 : 190

        let nextScale: CGSize = CGSize(width: gestureSuperView.bounds.width + dist, height: gestureSuperView.bounds.height + dist)
        
        if (nextScale.width >= (self.view.frame.width * 0.8)) || nextScale.width <= smallScale {
            return
        }
        
        gestureSuperView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: gestureSuperView.bounds.width + dist, height: gestureSuperView.bounds.height + dist)
    }
   }
```

i get distance with this method from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906659/20306199

```
func distance(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let xDist = a.x - b.x
    let yDist = a.y - b.y
    return CGFloat(sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist))
}
```

this works fine when object has no rotation, but i think when object is rotated upside down it still works with same coordinates but in reality it should those values in opposite manner, can anyone please help me to understand or achieve this, thanks.

Comment: Could you please share how you layout views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `distance(_:_:)` function, but in the `center` parameter. Your `center` parameter is determined in small images coordinate space, but `gestureLocation` is determined in view’s coordinate space. You can use `convert(_:to:)`  method to do that. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert).

UPD:
Actually you don't need to calculate distance between `frameScaleBut.center` and `gesture.location(in: self.view)`. Why? Because `self.initialDistance` almost always will be around 0. So `let dist = distance(center, touchLocation) - initialDistance` will always be positive. Instead calculate distance between `gestureSuperView.center` and `gesture.location(in: self.view)`. `gestureSuperView` is already in `view` coordinate space.

Comment: I don't have access to code base right now it's Diwali holidays from now on, so I will try this as soon as I will be back to job and inform you, Thank You.

Comment: after adding 
        `let center = superView.convert(frameScaleBut.center, to: self.view)`
it solves the problem and scaling in opposite direction works fine, but now when i try to scale it down it instead increases the the size even if it's rotated or not.

Comment: can you please help me with that

Comment: Sure, let me think about that a little bit

Comment: Updated, please check it out